# KeyboardWillShow only moves container UIView for certain UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have a container UIView that contains a UICollectionView and a UIView, both of which have UITextFields in them. I used `NSNotificationCenter` to move the container view when the keyboard pops up.

However, it only seems to work for the UICollectionView but not the sub UIView, as shown in the screenshots:

works fine for the text fields in UICollectionView:
[image: one]

but doesn't work for the text field in the UIView:

[image: two]  [image: three]

EDIT: related code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}



override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
            self.animateDurationView(true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.animateDurationView(false)
}

func animateDurationView(up: Bool) {
    var movement = (up ? -kbHeight : kbHeight)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.durationView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.durationView.frame, 0, movement)
    })
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you can share code instead of screenshots

Comment: if you're using AutoLayout, you shouldn't set frames. Connect the constraints as IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraints to your class interface or interface extension and update the constants instead, to adjust the views.

Comment: all of them? up to now, I've always just done "set to suggested constraints" so there's a lot in my view.