# UIView disappears when keyboard pops up for UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have an `UITextField` inside of a container view, when the keyboard pops up the container view disappears. In the same container view is a `UICollectionView`, whose custom cells each contains a `UITextField` and the keyboard works just fine for them.

I printed out the frame of the container view in the animation function that is called by `keyboardWillShow` and the container view's frames are the same for both cases, so it looks like the container view just disappears (instead of "not moved" as i thought) when that specific `UITextField` is selected. The relevant code is :

```swift
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
            self.animateDurationView(true)
        }
    }
}
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.animateDurationView(false)
}

func animateDurationView(up: Bool) {
    var movement = up ? -kbHeight : kbHeight
    println(movement)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.durationView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.durationView.frame, 0, movement)
        println(self.durationView.frame)
    })
}
```

the screenshots can be found in this thread: [KeyboardWillShow only moves container UIView for certain UITextFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504240/keyboardwillshow-only-moves-container-uiview-for-certain-uitextfields?noredirect=1#comment50971318_31504240)

EDIT: at this point I am almost certain that it is the auto layout constraints that are screwing with me.

Comment: Is your TextField/ContainerView setup such that when the keyboard is displayed they move so that the fields don't get overlaid by the keyboard (hidden)?

Comment: yes, that's why I moved the view

Comment: I have the same situation, when I turn AutoLayout OFF, it is working ok. So I can confirm that is related to AutoLayout/Constraints

Answer (score 1):

Try adding commitAnimations at the end of each animation transaction :) Me too I faced this issue... Now it is working fine.. You can add delegate to the textfield and you can move it delegate methods DidBeginEditing and DidEndEditing methods for textfield :)

Comment: Swift doesn't seem to have commitAnimations

Comment: ok. Better, you can use delegate methods of textfield for detecting the event of the textfield

Comment: I have already delegates in place. That doesn't solve it, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. What I did wrong was trying to apply the movement to an inner view. Moving the outermost view made it work as this outer view does not have any auto layout constraints.

So to answer the question - if anyone else should get here
Only move the self.view