# Locating auto layout constraints errors in the log

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm getting a bunch of auto layout constraints errors in my log, albeit there's none in my storyboard. I am having trouble understanding most of them especially locating specific views and text fields that are throwing errors:

```
2015-07-19 20:39:28.625 Daily[42447:417537] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3e309e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0(375)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc3f0 UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0.leading == UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc4e0 UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0.centerX == UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0.centerX>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc670 V:[UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0(81)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc6c0 UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0.width == 4.54321*UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc6c0 UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0.width == 4.54321*UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0.height>
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

2015-07-19 20:39:28.627 Daily[42447:417537] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3e309e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0(375)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcbf20 V:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4a50]-(76)-[UIView:0x7fd8a3dcb8b0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcbfc0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fd8a3dc4fb0]-(322)-[UIView:0x7fd8a3dcb8b0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc010 UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0.width == 3.25203*UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4a50.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc100 V:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dcc150]-(34)-[UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4a50]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc5d0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fd8a3dc4fb0]-(31)-[UIView:0x7fd8a3dcc150]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcdec0 H:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dcc150(368)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcdf10 UIView:0x7fd8a3dcc150.width == 6.34483*UIView:0x7fd8a3dcc150.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-07-19 20:39:28.628 Daily[42447:417537] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3e309e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0(375)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcbed0 UIView:0x7fd8a3dcb8b0.trailing == UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0.trailingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcbf70 UIView:0x7fd8a3dcb8b0.leading == UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dccf80 H:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dcb8b0(368)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dccf80 H:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dcb8b0(368)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-07-19 20:39:28.644 Daily[42447:417537] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3e309e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0(375)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc3f0 UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0.leading == UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc4e0 UIView:0x7fd8a3dc4ea0.centerX == UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0.centerX>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd8a3dcc620 H:[UIView:0x7fd8a3f416c0(368)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: are you using size classes in storyboard? have you checked nothing breaks if you swap to some of the more specialised sizes? and are you moving / resizing anything in code?

Answer (score 2):

You are adding wrong constraints to the views. If you adding centerX constraint then their is no need to add leading space constraint, it will conflict the constraint.  Add the constraint as centerX, height, width, & give Y position as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is appreciable. But, mostly I'd like to develop an app by disabling Auto-layout and classes. You need to set resize margins in the interface builder. If you're not clear with my solution, Please let me know, I'll explain it clearly :) :)

Comment: Yea I'm not really following, I'm pretty new to iOS development. I started with Swift and Auto Layout, but I'm getting the sense that Auto Layout is not as easy as it seems. I asked some other people and some of them told me that I can't just animate the UIViews, I need to change the constraints to achieve animation of the view. Some of them told me to abandon auto layout all together. So I'm kind of conflicted right now.

Comment: Also if you look at my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506480/uiview-disappears-when-keyboard-pops-up-for-uitextfield?noredirect=1#comment50975954_31506480) on stackoverflow, you can see the problem I ran into. And I'm almost certain that this problem of keyboard and UIView animation is caused by the above errors in Auto Layout constraints.

Comment: Oh, then you can need add suggested constraints in the bottom of the storyboard by clicking the triangle icon. But, I'd rather suggest to go with that disabling method and I'm not facing any issues and my apps can run in any devices at an exact alignment :)

Comment: Sorry for bombarding you with questions, but I also feel like I need a systematic knowledge or at least an overview of what kind of Interface Builder (xib, storyboard, auto layout) fits what situations.

Comment: how do you lay out the views when you disable auto layout?

Comment: If you're using xcode version 6.0+, you'll see the scale like image icon in the interface builder, It desctibes a plus kind of margin and resizing the view of that control that you selected.. Try using it and let me know, if you have any issues... I'm perfectly ok with that method..

Comment: Ok I will try it, thank you so much for all your help!